# csv comma seperated url conversion from plain urls to hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url, notepad++

i have a csv file full of plain image links

eg : `http://www.domain.com/galleries/big/gallery_69_1481.jpg,`

i have over a thousand of them to convert to a gallery images in wordpress's post content

i thought notepad ++ would be the easiest using regex. i cannot find anything that would allow me to prepend and append text on either end of the url to make it look like such

`<a href='http://www.domain.com/galleries/big/gallery_69_1481.jpg' title='' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery-1]'>,`

am i looking in the right direction or should i be looking for something else?

EDIT: my plain csv has this layout

```
"gallery_8_68.JPG,gallery_8_69.JPG,gallery_8_70.JPG,gallery_8_71.JPG,gallery_8_72.JPG,gallery_8_73.JPG,gallery_8_74.JPG,gallery_8_75.JPG,gallery_8_76.JPG,gallery_8_77.JPG,gallery_8_78.JPG,gallery_8_79.JPG,gallery_8_80.JPG,gallery_8_81.JPG,gallery_8_82.JPG,gallery_8_83.JPG",
```

and i want to make it look like

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/galleries/big/gallery_69_1489.jpg' title='' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery-1]'>,
```

Comment: So, basically, you want to convert `A,B,C,D,...` to `<a href="A" sth=else><some more code/></a>,<a href="B" sth=else>...,...`, right?

Comment: if it was a url per line that would be great but i have up to 50 image urls per block only comma seperated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it through notepad, you can use the Find/Replace regex function to do that.

Find:

```
[^,\r\n]+
```

Replace with:

```
<a href='$0' title='' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery-1]'>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gP2fE7)

---

`[^,\r\n]` is a negated class (a negated class has the form `[^ ... ]`). A negated class will match any character *except* those inside it. As such, `[^,\r\n]` will match all characters except commas, carriage returns and newlines. I added the carriage return and newline so that multiple lines don't get eaten into a single line (compare [this](http://regex101.com/r/pS6aP6) with [this](http://regex101.com/r/qI8gY9)).

`+` is a quantifier and means 1 or more occurrences of the previous pattern. So `[^,\r\n]+` means one or more character which is not a comma, carriage return or newline.

In the replace, every but the `$0` part is literal. `$0` is the matched pattern, and will contain the link that was matched.

---

Per your edit, you'll have to add some more characters to the regex and put more literal string in your replace...

Find:

```
[^,\r\n"]+\.JPG
```

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/galleries/big/$0' title='' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery-1]'>
```

[updated regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lG7xK9)

Make sure to uncheck the 'Match case' checkbox to match both `.JPG` and `.jpg`.

Comment: please could you tell me what the above regex does. i'm clueless

Comment: @DiZzY You should've put those specifications in your question earlier =/ I also added some explanation a little after your comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it does work! i noticed though that unless i manually select replace it will strip any text as well (i failed to mention that in my initial question)

Comment: @DiZzY Well... `i have a csv file full of plain image links` kind of implies there're only links in there... :( Do you have certain specific image formats? (Are all of them `.JPG`?)

Comment: they are all jpg. here is a pastebin of the my csv in notepad ++ [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RGUi18XS)

Comment: @DiZzY Okay then, you should be able to use [this](http://regex101.com/r/lG7xK9). Don't forget to also uncheck the 'Match case' checkbox so that both `.JPG` and `.jpg` are matched. Notice that I also added `"` in the negated class. I wasn't sure whether those for quoting or in the actual file, but it's now clear.

Comment: Many thanks @Jerry! you have saved me so many hours of manual labour!

Comment: @DiZzY You're welcome! Just remember that you make you question 100x clearer if you put a sample (like you did with pastebin) and the output you're looking for. You'd also have got your answer faster ;)

Comment: Hey Jerry. if i wanted to match a filename and extension     amandedeyib_gallery_151_3689.jpg what would the best regex be to use if there is a different seperator on either end ?

Comment: @DiZzY I'm not entirely sure what you mean by different separators, but you can modify the regex I gave you. Let's say the separator is `@` instead of `,`, you wouldn't want to match `@`, so the regex would become: `[^@\r\n"]+\.JPG` (Take note of what has changed). I saw your newer question, but haven't had the time to look at it properly. I admit that a quick glance gave me a bit of a headache because I couldn't relate the example with the end result :s

Comment: @DiZzY Awesome then :) I trust you know what to do if you have another separator now? ;)