# Match CSV image results with @ seperated text items

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, csv, notepad++

This is an expansion on my first question here [csv comma seperated url conversion from plain urls to hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366052/csv-comma-seperated-url-conversion-from-plain-urls-to-hyperlinks)

I have a CSV with comma seperated filenames that need to be matched up with captions that are enclosed with @@

http://pastebin.com/YZcum4wa with example layout

Some captions aren't present and therefore only @@ is present for the caption.

essentially i need the end result to look like

http://pastebin.com/AwY5enjp

In notepad the regex to replace the plain text filenames with hyperlinks worked like a charm. is that also possible to do for my above problem ?

Comment: That's pretty well, but what's the problem in your code?

Comment: I don't have code. i was doing the first regex match in notepad ++. i was hoping that there would be some way to match them up

Comment: I had a quick look at the two pastebin files and could not see what you meant by "filenames that need to be matched up with captions". Please provide proper examples here in you question and do not refer to external files that may be deleted in the future. Also please note that Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Stackoverflow aims to help people who have tried to solve their problem themselves. So please show what you have tried and explain why it does not do what you want.